# Max value from within ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, max

I've searched for this question so hopefully I'm not repeating anything...

I have 3 columns:

Column A - Names (ie David, Collin, Mary)

Column B - Sales  (50, 60, 45, 88)

Column C - Week (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

for example

```
Names Sales Week

David    1000     1
David    2000     1
David.   500      2
David    1000     2
Collin   300       1
Collin   500      1
Collin   800      2
Collin 100       2
```

At quick glance I can see that David's best weekly total was 3000 from week 1 and Collins was 900 from week 2.

Is there a formula to work out the above - one that gives the highest total for each person having calculated between the weeks?

Sorry if I haven't been clear :)

Comment: are the `.` spelling mistakes?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Ignore the . They are typos.   I have tried some sumproducts with Max too but i can't seem to get it right!

Comment: You can just edit your post and delete them. :)

Comment: Sounds like a job for a pivot table

Comment: Thank you I will try a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it works for me:

> Range A1:A8 refers to = Names
>
> Range b1:b8 refers to = Sale Amount
>
> Range c1:b8 refers to = Week Number

```
=MAX(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8="David")*($C$1:$C$8=1)*($B$1:$B$8)),SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8="David")*($C$1:$C$8=2)*($B$1:$B$8)),SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8="David")*($C$1:$C$8=3)*($B$1:$B$8)),SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8="David")*($C$1:$C$8=4)*($B$1:$B$8)),SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8="David")*($C$1:$C$8=5)*($B$1:$B$8)))
```

Comment: my bad, "Range c1:b8 refers to = Week" Number is  "Range c1:C8 refers to = Week Number"

Comment: Thank you! That works for me.. :) but is there a way to capture all the weeks? Rather than adding them each individually in the future to the formula? Doesn't matter if not, this works fine

Comment: Well all five weeks are accounted for. there shouldn't be problem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've got a workaround for your problem. But it's gonna look quite ugly. See if its help.

Firstly, to get the **unique combinations of Name-Week** enter the following formula in `Cell E2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15 & "," & $C$2:$C$15,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$15 &  "," & $C$2:$C$15),0,0),0)),"")
```

Then, to get the **sum of sales for each Name-Week** combination enter following formula in `Cell F2`

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$15,$A$2:$A$15,LEFT(E2,(FIND(",",E2,1)-1)),$C$2:$C$15,MID(E2,FIND(",",E2)+1,256))
```

This is an array formula so instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> together

Now, to get **unique names** from Column A enter following formula in `Cell G2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$A$2:$A$15),0,0),0)),"")
```

Finally, to get **Best Week Total** enter following formula in `Cell H2`

```
=MAX(IF(LEFT($E$2:$E$7,(FIND(",",$E$2:$E$7,1)-1))=G2,$F$2:$F$7))
```

Again, this is an array formula so instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> together.

**Note :** Based on data in your sheet, change the ranges in formula and drag/copy down as required.

This will give you result similar to below image:

[image]